# Convert 3rd party REST API into html forms?

Tags: api, rest

I want to convert an API service into a forms the user of my app can fill in. I think I need the right vocabulary to ask farther questions. Is there a term for this process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What type of content do you receive from the service? `application/json` is unfortunately not that helpful unless you analyze the parts it is sending and then create a mapping that generates your output. This is though a strong hint that this "REST API" isn't RESTful at all due to its tight coupling. A real REST service would send a well-defined and negotiated content-type that supports forms, like i.e. `_templates` does for [HAL-Forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), Amazons [Ion](https://ionspec.org/) or [Hydra's affordances](https://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/)

Answer (score 0):

Hydra is the only vocab I know about in the topic, though they don't support this kind of conversion. https://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/ HAL forms is another solution: https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/ but I guess based on the name that it is not abstract enough. You need to separate hyperlinks from forms. The former is for describing the interface of the webservice the later is for describing the GUI, which can use the webservice amongst many different types of clients. E.g. a select/choice parameter can be converted into radio button, checkbox, select input, range, etc. There needs to be some sort of mapping about this and this decision is made by the client developers, not by the service developers. Supporting multiple languages and labelling must be mapped too.

What you need is very detailed hyperlink descriptions and you can turn your hyperlinks into forms and hyperlink parameters into input fields. There are certain types of parameters e.g.

```
text (password?, multiline?, lengthRange, verified:regex|url|email|etc.)
repetition (source e.g. password double check)
select(alternatives[], selected[], selectionSize)
date(range, selectedRange, selectionSize)
time(range, selectedRange, selectionSize)
color(alternatives|range, selectedRange, selectionSize)
file(multi?, sizeRange, MIME-types[])
...
```

Better to support only what you need, because I think you need to write it yourself. Try to be very general, abstract instead of specific in this vocab. E.g. select can support select single and select multiple. The single can be supported with `selectionSize=1`. The alternatives can be added with a list or with another hyperlink which can be part of the response or lazy loaded, or it can be even an URI template which expects a keyword. The data of the fields can depend on each other, e.g. first you select city and the next field is street selection where you download the data by filling an URI template. So these fields can be interrelated and doing it properly requires a complex vocab.

From the REST API side of story binding these to the hyperlinks is relative easy:

```
{
    id: "/api/users/123"
    type: "/docs/User"
    userid: 123,
    addCar: {
        type: "/docs/User/addCar",
        method: "PUT",
        uri: {
            template: "/api/users/{id}/cars/{plateNumber}",
            id: {
                type: "docs/Text",
                range: "docs/Car/id",
                value: {
                    type: "/docs/Query",
                    context: "./resource",
                    select: "userid",
                },
                readOnly: true,
                required: true
            },
            plateNumber: {
                type: "/docs/Text",
                range: {
                    id: "/docs/Car/plateNumber",
                    verified: {
                        type: "/docs/verification/regex",
                        pattern: "[A-Z]{4,4}\d{2,2}"
                    }
                },
                required: true
            }
        },
        body: {
            brand: {
                type: "/docs/Selection",
                range: "/docs/Car/Brand/id",
                alternatives: {
                    type: "/docs/Car/Brand/listBrands",
                    method: "GET",
                    uri: "/api/car-brands"
                },
                value: null,
                selectionSize: [1,1],
                required: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The generated HTML form can be something like the following with radio input, but you can use select input too:

```
<form onsubmit="magic(this); return false">
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="123">
    <input type="text" id="plate_number" name="plate_number" pattern="[A-Z]{4,4}\d{2,2}" required="required"><br>
    <label for="plate_number">Plate Number</label><br>
    Select Brand:
    <input type="radio" id="brand_vw" name="brand" value="VW" required="required">
    <label for="brand_vw">Volkswagen</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="brand_ford" name="brand" value="Ford">
    <label for="brand_ford">Ford</label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Car">
</form>
```

The request is something like:

```
PUT /api/users/123/cars/ABCD12 {brand: "Ford"}
```

When you do it with an automated client you do:

```
carService.getUser({id: 123}).addCar({plateNumber: "ABCD12", brand: "Ford"})
```

When you do it with GUI, then:

```
carService = new Service("/docs")
// GET /docs/* might be cached
// or you can download a single JSON-LD docs file and use # for terms
// you bookmarked the getUser link from a previous call
// or you get it with GET /api/
// you can fill it with the actual user
user = carService.getUser({id: jwt.userId})
// GET /api/users/123
// you find the addCar link and generate a form from it
// GET /api/car-brands
// the user fills the form and sends it with magic
user.addCar({plateNumber: "ABCD12", brand: "Ford"})
// PUT /api/users/123/cars/ABCD12 {brand: "Ford"}
```

As you can see this can be very complicated and the upper hyperlink description is ad-hoc. If you need a proper RDF vocab, then it takes serveral years to design it properly. Still this kind of technique could be used in theory.

A complete client cannot be generated, because that involves knowing what you are doing or what you possibly need and in which part of the client. E.g. in this case it is where to display the form, when do we need this form and why, where to get the actual user id and the hyperlink from, etc. If the user has to decide everything about this, then in theory it can be generated and would look like a simple webpage, which can be browsed.